# How to have common module for select() in python sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 model classes from SQLAlchemy for my tables Table1 Table2 Table3

'''

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine , text , select, MetaData, Table  ,func , Column , String , Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy
from settings import DATABASE_URI
engine=create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
metadata = MetaData(bind=None)
session = Session()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    id = Column(u'id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name1 = Column(u'name1', String(50))

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    id = Column(u'id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name2 = Column(u'name2', String(50))

class Table3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table3'
    id = Column(u'id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name3 = Column(u'name3', String(50))


class connectionTest():
    def wrapper_connection(self,table,column,value):
        #SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE column = value
        query = session.query(table)
        q = query.filter_by(column = value)
        session.execute(q)


def main():
    ct = connectionTest()
    t1 = Table1()
    t2 = Table2()
    t3 = Table3()
    ct.wrapper_connection(t1,t1.name1, "Table1_Value_Information")
    ct.wrapper_connection(t2,t2.name2, "Table2_Value_Information")
    ct.wrapper_connection(t3,t3.name3, "Table3_Value_Information")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'''

I want the wrapper connection to handle all the 3 different tables with different columns. Basically to make this as generalized as possible to handle any condition related to (#SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE column = value) Clause through SQLAlchemy ORM or Core library.

The issue I am facing is in this line.
'q = query.filter_by(column = value)'

where I am trying to pass the column information from the function attribute t1.name1

ct.wrapper_connection(t1,t1.name1, "Table1_Value_Information")

Error I am facing:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\base.py", line 406, in _entity_descriptor
> return getattr(entity, key)

> AttributeError: type object 'Table1' has no attribute 'column'

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question needs three changes:

- In the `wrapper_connection` method, use `Query.filter` instead of `Query.filter_by` because it will accept a column object directly
- Don't call `Base.metadata.create_all()` until after the model classes have been declared
- `t1 = Table1()` creates a new *instance* of the `Table1` class - a row. You want to query against the table, so use the model classes directly instead.

```
class connectionTest:
    def wrapper_connection(self, table, column, value):
        # SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE column = value
        query = session.query(table)
        # We have the column object, so use filter
        # instead of filter_by
        q = query.filter(column == value)
        session.execute(q)


# Create the tables after the model classes have been declared.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


def main():
    ct = connectionTest()
    # Use the model classes directly.
    ct.wrapper_connection(Table1, Table1.name1, "Table1_Value_Information")
    ct.wrapper_connection(Table2, Table2.name2, "Table2_Value_Information")
    ct.wrapper_connection(Table3, Table3.name3, "Table3_Value_Information")
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.

Talking in the same context will this also works for Update and Delete wrapper module?

Currently I have to multiple functions for  multiple columns wherein **self.tablename.c.name** is a python object which always changes.

'def delete_column(self ,session,  column_value): 
        stmt=self.tablename.delete().where(self.tablename.c.name == column_value)
        session.execute(stmt)
        session.commit()'

Defined table by Reflecting database object:
'self.tablename = Table(table, metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)'